# Why does my function comprised of asynchronous functions not returning correct value? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, async-await

A variable which is assigned within async functions is not returning the expected output.

I am currently writing a NodeJS function that finds an object from a MongoDB database (the database works perfectly) and returns an object if it is found. The problem is that the functions' comprising async functions don't wait until the previous functions are finished. I am relatively new to JS and NodeJS, so it may be that I am misunderstanding how the async functions act.

```
async function findUserByEmail (userEmail) {
    var mg = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    var user;

    await mg.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, async function(err, db){
        var dbo = db.db(myDB);
        var query = { email : userEmail };

        await dbo.collection("Users").findOne(query).then((result)=>{
            user = result;
            db.close();
        });
    });

    return user;
}
```

I am trying to return the value assigned to "user" within the "findOne(query)" function, however, the value returned is always "undefined".

Comment: you can fetch it with `var user = await mg.connect....` and using `return await dbo.collection....` and `return result;` after `db.close()`. But I'm curious of why it doesn't work like this.

Comment: what is your current node version ? You could try with other versions, it was maybe fixed in some version.

Comment: I am using version 6.9.0. I have also tried your first comment and it still seems to be giving the same problem

Comment: You could try to upgrade to node `8.16.0`, using the package `n` for example. ( `npm install -g n && n 8.16.0`)

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing callbacks and asynchronous calls. So Let me just clean it up. And voila here you go something that should work (You have some values that I don't know e.g myDB and url).

```
async function findUserByEmail (userEmail) {
    var mg = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var db = await mg.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    var result;

    // Add a Try/Catch to capture any errors, 
    // such that the database can still be closed
    try {  
        var dbo = db.db(myDB);
        var query = { email : userEmail };
        result = await dbo.collection("Users").findOne(query);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;   
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Note**: I recommend opening the MongoDB connection once when the application starts, reopen it when it closes for any reason and close it when the application stops, since opening a new connection for every request adds some significant overhead (think like potentially 25x slower).

Comment: Probably  want a `try/catch` so you can close the database if any of the previous `await` statements reject.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do agree, but in general I wouldn't recommend opening and closing a database connection in the same function as a fetching function anyway. It has some significant overhead.

Comment: Now you're "eating" the error and not letting the caller see a rejected promise if the query rejects.

Comment: OK, you got it now.  I agree, btw, on the notion of not opening and closing a DB connection just for one query.  FYI, you don't need the `catch` unless you want to log the error there.  Just the `try/finally` will do just fine.